# Azure MS Access database - best location?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, azure, azure-virtual-machine, appdata

My company is considering migrating our systems to Azure. We have an asp .net web application running with Access Database. My boss doesn't want to use SQL azure just yet - he may want it one day but for now we will stick with ms Access. Where would be the best place to put our Access Database?

I have been doing some tests and it seems to work just fine when it's located in the Azure website directory inside App_Data folder. However, I am not sure if this is a safe approach.

The other option I have read about is putting in on a virtual machine.

I am not sure which approach to take. The point is to keep using MS Access with an Azure website

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624347/security-of-app-data-folder-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for this but it's not touching on how Azure treats this

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option i suggest. We keep the access file into Blob storage and make the connection string pointing to a Blob storage path.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? How would the connection string look like?