# asp.net multiple uploads with multiple fileupload control

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net, file-upload

I'm working in tiny project that deal with multiple file uploading.

at the begining user have **one fileupload control** and **a small image** called **fileuploadadder** .

**each time** user click on fileuploadadder , a **clone** of the **first fileupload** control added to the page with **jquery** . the **ids** of the fileupload controls are **uniqe**. such as file1 , file2, ...

now , i want when user clicks on a button at the end of the page asp.net uploads the selected files.

tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    protected void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Files != null)
        {
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var uploadedFile = Request.Files[file];
                if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var appData = Server.MapPath("~/app_data");
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                    uploadedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(appData, fileName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <a href="#" id="add">Add file</a>
        <div id="files"></div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="BtnUpload_Click" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#add').click(function () {
            $('#files').append($('<input/>', {
                type: 'file',
                name: 'file' + new Date().getTime()
            }));
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: App_data folder should not be used to upload such files, because this is a special folder reserved for data such as database files.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar, it's just an example. And there's nothing bad of using the `App_Data` folder for storing uploaded files as shown by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx. It is not reserved exclusively for database.

Comment: hmm, but I have a problem using this folder before 2 years ago when I was working. I have post the issue on StackOverflow. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519790/images-that-are-in-app-data-folder-not-shown-in-browser

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar, the problem you had is that you was trying to serve files from this folder directly to the client. This of course is not possible as files from this folder are not served by ASP.NET. What I usually do is to use a HTTP handler to serve uploaded files from this folder. This allows me to control which user access which file.

Comment: hmm right. thanks for clarification. Can you give me an reference link for just my personal understanding?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar, reference link for what?