# How to select multiple files at a time in file upload control?

Tags: asp.net

How to select multiple files at a time in file upload control and whatever the files selected that I want to show on a popup with remove option. Please have a look on below images.
[image: Selecting multiple files at a time]

[image: showing the selected files in a popup with remove and upload option]

Comment: simple google search would have solved your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806574/asp-net-multiple-uploads-with-multiple-fileupload-control

Comment: I googled, but not able to do this. Please help me out.