# Get image path from webapi run on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I store image in folder App_Data in project Web API. I stored in the database with the path:

```
 var path = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), user.Username + ext);
```

From project MVC client i call Web Api, from path image i cannot show tag `<img />`. Chrome show error: Not allowed to load local resource.

```
<img id="img_id"  width="70px" heigh="70px" src="D:\Nguyen Nhu\Lap Trinh Hien Dai\ServerAPI\ServerAPI\App_Data\nophoto.gif"/>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should use [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.108).aspx) and not `Server.MapPath` to map served client Urls in MVC. [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) returns the physical folder, and should be used only by server-side code.

However, `App_Data` is a special folder and files stored there [won't be served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519790/images-that-are-in-app-data-folder-not-shown-in-browser) by IIS.

**TL;DR**: You'll need to use another folder to store your images in, e.g.

`Url.Content('~/MyImagesFolder/' + user.Username + ext);`

Comment: I can't call Url.Content method not exist.

Comment: At a guess, you are creating the Url in a data layer, away from MVC, hence the error. Can I suggest that you store just the filename (e.g. `user.UserName + ext`) in your database, and then create the served image url when you render the page, using `Url.Content`. This will have several benefits, notably portability of file storage location.