# Show image stored in App_Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, app-data

I have 2 image files in my App_Data directory and I want to show them in my view like this:

```
@foreach (var media in Model)
{
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
         <a class="thumbnail"><img src="@Url.Content("~/App_Data/uploads/" + @media.URL)" alt="image" /></a>
      </div>
}
```

When I check the link in the browser I get this :

```
<img src="/App_Data/uploads/Warnings.png" alt="image">
```

It says he can't find the image. How can I set the correct link?

Comment: Check if you had a web.config configured in App_Data folder, this can cause many problems. Anyways you should not store images in this folder.

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito is right. You really shouldn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519790/images-that-are-in-app-data-folder-not-shown-in-browser

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The App_Data folder is a special .NET "system" folder in which IIS is configured to not allow the contents of that folder to be visible to web users.  Create a different folder to store your images as you really should not allow App_Data to be web visible (if you can even change the setting).

[From iis.net](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments):

> For example, on Web servers that are hosting ASP.NET content, IIS 7
>   blocks several of the ASP.NET-related paths for you; Web.config, bin,
>   App_Code, etc. Blocking these URL segments reduce the chance of an
>   attacker being able to exploit these URLs for information.